# Trouble Defining Nullable Lists in Avro Schema - Pub/Sub Google Cloud

Tags: arrays, json, schema, avro, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm encountering a puzzling issue while working with **Avro schema** validation and message testing, specifically within a **Google Cloud Pub/Sub schema**. In my schema, I've defined a list of custom objects that can be nullable.

However, when I try to validate a sample JSON message like this:

```json
{
  "nullable_list": [
    {"field1": 10, "field2": "example1"},
    {"field1": 20, "field2": "example2"}
  ]
}
```

I'm getting the error message: "*The message is not valid according to the schema*."

Surprisingly, if I provide a JSON message like this:

```json
{
  "nullable_list": null
}
```

It indicates that: "*The message is valid according to the schema.*"

Here's my schema:

```json
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "MyRecord",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "nullable_list",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "record",
            "name": "MyObject",
            "fields": [
              {"name": "field1", "type": "int"},
              {"name": "field2", "type": "string"}
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "default": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Can someone please explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Avro JSON Encoding specification](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.11.1/specification/#json-encoding):

> The value of a union is encoded in JSON as follows:
>
> - if its type is null, then it is encoded as a JSON null;
> - otherwise it is encoded as a JSON object with one name/value pair whose name is the type’s name and whose value is the recursively
>   encoded value. For Avro’s named types (record, fixed or enum) the
>   user-specified name is used, for other types the type name is used.

Therefore, the proper JSON representation of this message would be:

```
{
    "nullable_list": {
        "array": [
            {
                "field1": 10,
                "field2": "example1"
            },
            {
                "field1": 20,
                "field2": "example2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```